# Forward declaration of inline function within class member causes linker error

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
struct Foo {
    float f;
    
    Foo& operator+=(Foo rhs) {
        Foo operator+(Foo, Foo);
        *this = *this + rhs;
        return *this;
    }
};

inline Foo operator+(Foo lhs, Foo rhs) {
    return Foo{lhs.f + rhs.f};
}
```

If and only if `operator+(Foo, Foo)` is defined as `inline`, GCC and MSVC give "undefined reference to operator+(Foo, Foo)" linker errors, while Clang has no issues. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/KWzx5n) for a live example.

I would presume this code is valid; the `inline`-ness of the function should have no effect, since the function should not need to be declared as `inline` if it's defined as `inline` (and anyway, a function cannot be declared `inline` at block scope).
Note that if `operator+(Foo, Foo)` is instead declared (as non-`inline`) before the definition of `Foo`, it is accepted by all 3 compilers.

However, such issues as linkage are tricky within the Standard, so I'm aware it could also be undefined behaviour or "ill-formed, no diagnostic required" and GCC and MSVC just happen to give errors.

**So is this code valid?** Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Your presumption is incorrect. This is not valid C++. This is not a forward declaration but a nested function declaration. Nested functions, like that, is not standard C++. You are using a compiler extension, and incorrectly. All these compilers are correct, it's just that the definition of "correct" is different, for each compiler.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - There's no nested function in sight. It's a declaration, which may appear in block scope.

Comment: BTW, one can reduce the example further https://wandbox.org/permlink/M08QvRZOxJcj3LYx - Apparently, it's about one inline function containing a declaration of another, defined later.

Comment: On a side note, these are normally implemented the other way around; `+` using `+=`. Your way creates a slightly awkward dependence of the class on the outside world.

Comment: @molbdnilo - true that these operators are usually implemented the other way around but what do you mean by "dependence of the class on the outside world"?

Comment: If `operator+(Foo, Foo)` is declared before the struct as inline, GCC compiles as well (i.e. it doesn't strictly have to be declared as non-inline before the struct). It seems like it just needs some declaration or another before the struct definition, which does seem quite strange.

Comment: I think the code is valid, but can't write an answer right now.

Comment: [Similar GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51757), except that the inline function is not manually defined at the namespace scope but injected by the friend declaration.

Comment: Works in GCC trunk, BTW.

Comment: It works on my local gcc 9.3.0 -std=c++17, however not on wandbox, same settings.

Comment: Probably fixed by https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/4e62aca0e0520e4ed2532f2d8153581190621c1a

Comment: @molbdnilo I just realised the compound assignment operators can be defined as nonmembers (which I didn't think was possible, hence why I ended up with this code). So, from a practical perspective, that completes alleviates the issue with minimal change in design.